# From JavaFX 2.2 to JavaFX8

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have made an application using JavaFX 2.2 and want to switch to JavaFX 8. Using JavaFX2.2 my application looks like this:

[image: JavaFX 2.2]

When using JavaFX 8 without changing any source code it looks like this:

[image: JavaFX8]

With JavaFX8 some nodes are not shown at all (e.g. Criterion 1) and sometimes appear after clicking randomly on the scrollpane. In addition the nodes have an incorrect size (compare Step 1 and the small little dot). Another problem is that when performing actions such as adding nodes the application lags heavily in JavaFX8.

Unfortunately I do not get any error messages at all and I have almost no clue what I have to fix in order to get the application working in JavaFX8. Any help/ideas/hints would be greatly appreciated.

Possible issues (?):

- I have used Platform.runLater() very often in my application. Has this perhaps changed in JavaFX 8?
- in JavaFX2.2 the size of a node (e.g. stackpane containing text) was automatically computed after adding it to the scroll pane. Let's say I add a node with position x and y. Only after JavaFX has drawn it I can get its height and width (boundsInParent.getHeight()). This is also the reason why I often used Platform.runLater() in order to layout the nodes. Has this behaviour changed in JavaFX 8?

EDIT: The "bug" is connected with css styling. If I remove the stylesheets that are added to the nodes everything works fine (except the styling of the nodes of course). In particular the commands I have to remove are of the following form:

getStylesheets().add(ClassName.class.getResource("CSSFile.css").toExternalForm());

Comment: I had a possibly (possibly not) similar problem. It had to do with property listeners/bindings being connected with `WeakReference`s in JavaFX 8. If you could reproduce this problem (i.e. a simple app that works well in JavaFX 2.2 but has the above behavior in JavaFX 8), maybe I (or somebody else) could help.

Comment: Just a comment: it doesn't really surprise me that your code doesn't work across JDK versions given the description of how you have implemented your layout. `Platform.runLater()` means "Do this at some point in the future on the FX Application Thread"; it doesn't mean "Do this once the layout bounds have been computed". So the fact that your code "works" in JavaFX 2.2 is really just an incidental side effect of how the library was implemented. Can you not use standard layout techniques instead of trying to manage the layout in a low-level way yourself?

Comment: @James_D Well, is there any technique to layout nodes based on their bounds without using Platform.runLater()? I have searched extensively for a way to force JavaFX to "draw" the elements so that I can use their size in my computations, however the only solution I found was Platform.runLater(). Nevertheless, I removed all lines of code with Platform.runLater() in order to test whether this impacted it, however it did not help at all.

Comment: All the standard layout panes lay nodes out based on their bounds. Can you not use those instead of trying to reinvent the wheel? If there is no combination of existing layout panes that meet your requirements, the next option is to subclass `Pane` and override the `layoutChildren()` method. If I needed this (I never have), I would probably look into the [source code for existing layout panes](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/graphics/src/main/java/javafx/scene/layout) to see how it is done there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have identified the error: I had one negative value within my css stylesheet (which was used for the nodes). Removing that value made it work like in JavaFX 2.2. To be precise I had to change the following:

```
-fx-border-width: 5 -1 0 5 ;
```

to

```
-fx-border-width: 5 0 0 5 ;
```